# Compare-Object and Export-Clixml

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to understand how Compare-Object works.
I wrote this snipper

```
PS> Get-Service -Name bits | Export-Clixml -Path .\example.xml
PS> sleep 1
PS> Get-Service -Name bits | Export-Clixml -Path .\example2.xml
  > fc example.xml example2.xml
    Comparing files example.xml and EXAMPLE2.XML
    FC: no differences encountered

PS> sleep 1
PS> Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Import-Clixml -Path .\example.xml) -DifferenceObject (Get-Service -Name bits)
```

I get:

```
InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
bits        =>
bits        <=
```

but I don't understand why the two objects differ. I tried to execute the export command multiple times to see if there is a time-related parameter in the xml.. but there is not!

So, where is the error?

Rr

Comment: Please post the exported xml and imported xml that you are comparing.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. The import-export is the same file. The file is huge (300rows). 
Can you try the snippet on you own PC (bits is a common service on all win*)

Comment: ```Import-Clixml -Path .\example.xml``` returns a ```PSCustomObject```, but ```Get-Service -Name bits``` returns a  ```System.ComponentModel.Component.ServiceController```. ```Compare-Object``` determines these to be *not* equal, and so shows them both as a "!difference" on their respective sides.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mclayton I think that it is not possible to use the Compare-Object in this way

```
> Get-Service -Name bits | Get-Member             
   TypeName: System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController

> Import-Clixml -Path .\example.xml | Get-Member
   TypeName: Deserialized.System.Service.ServiceController#StartupType
```

These are two different classes.

Rr

Comment: Yup, compare object is majorly for files only which compares line by line. Not between to different variance of objects. 

if you do `Compare-Object (Import-Clixml -Path .\example.xml) (Import-Clixml -Path .\example2.xml) -IncludeEqual` , you will get `== ` only as side indicator.

Comment: Thanks. I finally get the idea about how to use this cmdlet!

Comment: Note that if the values are arrays (or generally enumerable), the items don't need to be in the same order - e.g. ```Compare-Object @(3, 2, 1) @(2, 3, 4)``` will output ```4 =>``` and ```1 <=```, telling you the left side has an extra ```1``` and the right side has an extra ```4```.